# How to reduce time interval and average observations?

Tags: r, excel, datetime, binary-data, reduce

I have two columns of data: a time column in the format DD/MM/YY HH.MM and a column with binary data for each time cell, eg:

```
Time                Set
2015-01-02 14:39:35 0
2015-01-02 14:39:36 1
2015-01-02 14:40:11 0
2015-01-02 14:40:50 1
2015-01-04 07:53:47 0
2015-01-04 07:54:17 1
2015-01-04 12:18:02 0
```

I would like to change the time interval to a fixed one, say five minutes, and show the average value of the observations in this interval.

Is there some way this can be done in Excel with filtering or VBA macro, or perhaps in R?

I hope it is possible to help without any reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
time <- as.POSIXct(strsplit("2015-01-02 14:39:35, 2015-01-02 14:39:36, 2015-01-02 14:40:11, 2015-01-02 14:40:50,2015-01-04 07:53:47, 2015-01-04 07:54:17, 2015-01-04 12:18:02", ",\\s?")[[1]])
set <- sample(c(0, 1), size = length(time), replace = TRUE)
aggregate(set, list(groups <- cut(time, breaks = "5 mins")), mean)
#      Group.1   x
# 1 2015-01-02 14:39:00 0.5
# 2 2015-01-04 07:49:00 0.0
# 3 2015-01-04 07:54:00 0.0
# 4 2015-01-04 12:14:00 1.0
```

The 5-minute-intervals are stored in `groups`.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED Assuming Time is in ColumnA. Unfortunately Grouping and Average for Values do not go together well in PivotTables but you might try adding a column to your data (say insert a new ColumnA) with `1` in A2 and a formula such as:

```
 =IF(B3-B2>1/288,A2+1,A2)
```

in A3, copied down to suit.

Then include that in your PT as the first item for ROWS, `Time` the second item there and `Set` in VALUES with Average selected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies

So far I created a new column in which I rounded the time data up or down to the nearest 5 minutes, with:

= (ROUND((B2 * 1440) / 5; 0) * 5) / 1440

where B2 is the first data point in the original time column

So far so good
I think I can get the rest of the way just in Excel..and not R

The new time column is now something like:
03-01-2015 07:00:00, 03-01-2015 07:05:00, 03-01-2015 07:05:00, 03-01-2015  14:25:00 03-01-2015 14:25:00, ....

Now I want to "collapse" the time and observation data, into 1 data point for each 5 min and have 1 value for each time, either 0 or 1 representing the majority of the numbers in the range of e.g. 07:05:00-observations.
So that the time column becomes:
03-01-2015 07:00:00, 03-01-2015 07:05:00, 03-01-2015 14:25:00, ...

Does it make sense?